# Is it safe to to upgrade OS X 10.7 to 10.8 on a productive system?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I was wondering if there are any implications to upgrading my iMac web development machine (which is highly configured MAMP (Apache, MySQl), customized hosts file, custom Network Card settings, etc... from OS X 10.7 to OS X 10.8?

Will I loose everything 9apps/files/MAMP config, etc...

Comment: You shouldn't lose anything - but 10.8 is going to be hard to get hold of these days; you can't get it from Apple any more [unless it's in your purchase history already]

Comment: Depending on how you installed them your executables might need recompiling - they depend on dynamic libraries and if they are supplied in the OS the API might have changed with the newer versions

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time the OS X upgrade routines work quite reliably and in this case there shouldn't be any deal-breakers like [Rosetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)) back in the days. However, it is impossible to tell for sure. What I usually do, is to clone my system to either a [second partition in the internal drive](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/06/how-to-create-a-test-partition-for-the-os-x-yosemite-beta/) or to an external (USB) drive (using a tool like [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com)).

After booting the clone (press <kbd>alt</kbd> in the boot screen) you can safely upgrade this partition to a newer version of OS X and play with it for a while. Once you are sure everything works, you can either copy it back to your main partition or upgrade that one too.

Nevertheless, I recommend to have another (e.g. TimeMachine) backup available, in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: @John Was this answer helpful? Do you need further info?